# Find the maximal area of a quadrilateral inside of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, optimization, maxima-minima, rectangles, quadrilateral

**Problem:**

> In a rectangle $ABCD$ we know that $AB=3$ and $BC=1$. If $M$ is a point of side $AD$ and $N$ is a point of side $AB$, such that $AN=2AM$, what is the maximal possible area of the quadrilateral $MNCD$?

**Solution:**

> $$\frac{7}{4}$$

How do we even approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Think about the triangles $MAN$ and $NBC$, depicted above.

Triangle $MAN$ has area $x^2$ and triangle $NBC$ has area $\frac{3}{2} - x$.

The area of the quadrilateral $MNCD$ is the area of the rectangle $ABCD$ minus the areas of these triangles, thus $MNCD$ has area $\frac{3}{2} + x - x^2$.

This is now a calculus problem:  maximize $\frac{3}{2} + x - x^2$ subject to $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: $MAN$ has area $x^2$? Don't you think it is $x^2/2$?

Comment: I think the area of the triangle is $1/2 \times \text{base} \times \text{height} = 1/2 \times x \times 2x = x^2$

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry. Stupid question.

Comment: :) no worries at all

Answer (score 2):

Let $AM=a$.

Thus, $AN=2a$, $NB=3-2a$ and the area it's
$$3\cdot1-\frac{1}{2}a\cdot2a-\frac{1}{2}1\cdot(3-2a)=-a^2+a+\frac{3}{2}=$$
$$-a^2+a-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=-\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{7}{4}\leq\frac{7}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $a=\frac{1}{2},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: From where did you get $...\leq\frac{7}{4}$?

Comment: @Hanlon It's $\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{4}.$ I added something. See now.

Comment: Thanks, but that's now what I meant. I meant, why does the $-\left(a-1/2)\right)^2+7/3$ is limited with $7/4$, and when I say "limited" I mean "can be lower and equal, but not higher". And also, how do you know that if $a=1/2$ we've got the maximal value?

Comment: Because $-\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\leq0.$